# Shortcut to Eclipse in /Applications

Tags: macos, applications, eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse for OS X. I managed to run it, but I want to put it directly in `/Applications`:

I don't want to place the `eclipse` folder, which has inside it the `Eclipse.app`, inside `/Applications`, but I want to place a shortcut to `Eclipse.app` directly into `/Applications` (so I can run `eclipse` with one click, as if it was any other app inside `/Applications`).

Any ideas how to do so? Tried a symlink but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symlink won't work as at the command line level an application is a directory.

Make an alias to the Eclipse application in the Finder and drop that into /Applications and it will work fine.

By the way, you will see in the eclipse folder a file `eclipse` which is a link to the actual Eclipse unix executable that lives in `Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS` alongside the `eclipse.ini` file that defines all the startup options. You might want to replicate that link to somewhere in your PATH so that you can run Eclipse from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

- Right clic on Eclipse.app > Make alias
- Move the alias into `/Application`

Answer (score 2):

Simple steps to follow:

- Open **Finder**
- Click **Go** (option at top of screen)
- Click **Home**
- Double click Eclipse folder and find your eclipse app
- Now select Eclipse app, hold command key and drag and drop it
  in Application folder (showing left side panel in Finder)

All done.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ln` command will indeed create an alias to an app in /Applications, provided you use sudo.

You might want to try:

```
sudo ln -s <full path to Eclipse.app> /Applications
```